# Implementing a custom callback in a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, callback

I am using web services - not WCF - hosted in an iis web application written in C#/asp.net. I also have a C# winform Desktop application that had originally polled a web method to check for any messages on the server. I found the memory on the client shot up.  So, instead of polling this web method I invoke it once, the web method goes into a loop checking for messages. As soon as it finds a message(s) for this client it breaks out of the loop and returns the message(s) to the client. The client in turn will process the message(s) and then re-invoke the same web method waiting for the next message(s).

I run this and the memory on the client desktop and the memory on the web server remain low.  I really have 2 questions here.

1). Will the memory escalate on the server when more clients invoke the same web method?
2). Should I avoid this way of doing things?

I know there are callbacks available using WCF and I know I can create a hub using Signal R. what I would like to know is there anything wrong/different to how I am doing it and/or is there a better way of doing it?

Many Thanks.

Comment: fixing the memory problem on the client seems like the easiest fix.  Are you forgetting to dispose something?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your feedback.  There are no memory leaks as far as I can see.  It is because it is in a infinite loop - constantly checking for messages that I get this memory consumption.